# Driver causing a system crash every time unloaded

Tags: c++, windows, driver, windbg

The driver I wrote is taken from the Windows Kernel Programming book but for some reason it just doesn't work.

Here is my driver entry:

```
extern "C" NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath) {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(RegistryPath);
    auto status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    InitializeListHead(&g_Globals.ItemsHead);
    g_Globals.Mutex.Init();
    PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject = nullptr;
    UNICODE_STRING symLink = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"\\??\\sysmon");
    bool symLinkCreated = false;
    do {
        UNICODE_STRING devName = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"\\Device\\sysmon");
        status = IoCreateDevice(DriverObject, 0, &devName,
            FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, 0, TRUE, &DeviceObject);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            KdPrint((DRIVER_PREFIX "failed to create device (0x%08X)\n",
                status));
            break;
        }
        DeviceObject->Flags |= DO_DIRECT_IO;
        status = IoCreateSymbolicLink(&symLink, &devName);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            KdPrint((DRIVER_PREFIX "failed to create sym link (0x%08X)\n",
                status));
            break;
        }
        symLinkCreated = true;
        // register for process notifications
        status = PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx(OnProcessNotify, FALSE);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            KdPrint((DRIVER_PREFIX "failed to register process callback (0x%08X)\n",
                status));
            break;
        }
        status = PsSetCreateThreadNotifyRoutine(OnThreadNotify);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            KdPrint((DRIVER_PREFIX "failed to set thread callbacks (status=%08X)\n", status)\
            );
            break;
        }

    } while (false);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        if (symLinkCreated)
            IoDeleteSymbolicLink(&symLink);
        if (DeviceObject)
            IoDeleteDevice(DeviceObject);
    }
    DriverObject->DriverUnload = SysMonUnload;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CREATE] =
        DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CLOSE] = SysMonCreateClose;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_READ] = SysMonRead;
    return status;
}
```

now this function works well but i'm pretty sure the problem lies around here.

here is the SysMonCrearteClose function which also fails (I must say that I don't fully understand what I need to code in this function however even without calling it the driver failes, I'm sure there is a problem in here as well):

```
NTSTATUS SysMonCreateClose(_In_ PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, _In_ PIRP Irp) { 
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DeviceObject);
    Irp->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    Irp->IoStatus.Information = 0;
    IoCompleteRequest(Irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

now here is the SysMonUnload function:

```
void SysMonUnload(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject) {
    // unregister process notifications
    PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx(OnProcessNotify, TRUE);
    UNICODE_STRING symLink = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"\\??\\sysmon");
    IoDeleteSymbolicLink(&symLink);
    IoDeleteDevice(DriverObject->DeviceObject);
    // free remaining items
    while (!IsListEmpty(&g_Globals.ItemsHead)) {
        auto entry = RemoveHeadList(&g_Globals.ItemsHead);
        ExFreePool(CONTAINING_RECORD(entry, FullItem<ItemHeader>, Entry));
    }
}
```

Here is the last function that matters, the SysMonRead function:

```
NTSTATUS SysMonRead(PDEVICE_OBJECT, PIRP Irp) {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Irp);
    auto stack = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);
    auto len = stack->Parameters.Read.Length;
    auto status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    auto count = 0;
    NT_ASSERT(Irp->MdlAddress); // we're using Direct I/O
    auto buffer = (UCHAR*)MmGetSystemAddressForMdlSafe(Irp->MdlAddress,
        NormalPagePriority);
    if (!buffer) {
        status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
    }
    else {
        AutoLock lock(g_Globals.Mutex);
        while (true) {
            if (IsListEmpty(&g_Globals.ItemsHead)) // can also check g_Globals.ItemCount
                break;
            auto entry = RemoveHeadList(&g_Globals.ItemsHead);
            auto info = CONTAINING_RECORD(entry, FullItem<ItemHeader>, Entry);
            auto size = info->Data.Size;
            if (len < size) {
                // user's buffer is full, insert item back
                InsertHeadList(&g_Globals.ItemsHead, entry);
                break;
            }
            g_Globals.ItemCount--;
            ::memcpy(buffer, &info->Data, size);
            len -= size;
            buffer += size;
            count += size;
            // free data after copy
            ExFreePool(info);
        }

        

    }
    Irp->IoStatus.Status = status;
    Irp->IoStatus.Information = count;
    IoCompleteRequest(Irp, 0);
    return status;

}
```

throughout the program I allocate memory that is freed in the unload routine and open handles to files and mutexes which I also close. Whenever I load this driver the functionality intended is working properly (when I write to a file it works, the CreateClose function does not work) however when I unload the driver the system crashes. I used windbg to try and see what the issue is to no avail, here is the error message:

```
*** Fatal System Error: 0x000000ce
                       (0xFFFFF80260A71390,0x0000000000000010,0xFFFFF80260A71390,0x0000000000000000)

Driver at fault: ProcessThreadMonitorDriver.sys.
Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
nt_exe!DbgBreakPointWithStatus:
```

I noticed sometimes it said something about an invalid memory access but it was inconsistent and unclear.

Comment: It's been a *very* long time since I did any deep-down coding on a Windows device driver but, to me, it looks like a lot of the code you have in your `DriverEntry` belongs more properly in your `AddDevice`. Maybe things have changed since "The Olde Days"? The `DriverEntry` routine should be setting up the various function fields in the passed object and little else, IIRC.

Comment: That's DRIVER_UNLOADED_WITHOUT_CANCELLING_PENDING_OPERATIONS, fits the bill rather well and tells you where to look.  SysMonUnload() does not clean up the OnThreadNotify notification callback.  If you copied this code from the book then be sure to google for the book's errata.

Comment: Where do you call `PsRemoveCreateThreadNotifyRoutine`?